# Access method that generates migration ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there anyway to access the method that is called that creates the database migration when you call `Add-Migration` in Entity Framework Core?

This is in a .NET Core 2.2 project, if that makes a difference.

Comment: why do you need to access it?

Comment: Because I would like to change the order of the columns that are being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the `Migration`, you could implement `MigrationsAssembly`.

1. Implement `ColumnOrderMigrationAssembly`

   ```
   public class ColumnOrderMigrationAssembly : MigrationsAssembly
   {
       private readonly DbContext _context;

       public ColumnOrderMigrationAssembly(ICurrentDbContext currentContext,
           IDbContextOptions options, IMigrationsIdGenerator idGenerator,
           IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Migrations> logger)
       : base(currentContext, options, idGenerator, logger)
       {
           _context = currentContext.Context;
       }

       public override Migration CreateMigration(TypeInfo migrationClass,
           string activeProvider)
       {
           var migration = base.CreateMigration(migrationClass, activeProvider);
           var productTableMigration = migration.UpOperations.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType() == typeof(CreateTableOperation) 
           && ((CreateTableOperation)m).Name == "Products") as CreateTableOperation;
           if (productTableMigration != null)
           {
               var columns =new List<AddColumnOperation>(productTableMigration.Columns.OrderBy(o => o.Name));
               productTableMigration.Columns.Clear();
               productTableMigration.Columns.AddRange(columns);
           }
           return migration;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `ColumnOrderMigrationAssembly`

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
           .ReplaceService<IMigrationsAssembly, ColumnOrderMigrationAssembly>());
   ```
3. Enable `migrate`

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
       //your rest code
       using (var db = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
       {
           db.Database.Migrate();
       }
   }
   ```

   Change the logic in `CreateMigration` for your own requirement.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you @TaoZhou

Answer (score 0):

under the project where you run the Add-Migration there is a folder called Migration, it is where the Migration classes are being added. You can change the order of columns when you re-run your migration.

Comment: When you have over 100 tables I am sure as hell not going to manually update the migration file.